# Show the oldest or newest records without showing the date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following tables:

`account`

```
+------------+--------------+
| account_id | account_name |
+------------+--------------+
|        452 | a            |
|        785 | b            |
|        985 | c            |
+------------+--------------+
```

and

`task`

```
+---------+------------+------------+
| task_id | task_date  | account_id |
+---------+------------+------------+
|       2 | 01-01-2013 |        452 |
|       1 | 14-02-2013 |        452 |
|       5 | 03-01-2013 |        452 |
|       1 | 02-02-2013 |        785 |
|       7 | 07-01-2013 |        785 |
|       5 | 01-03-2013 |        785 |
|       1 | 25-03-2013 |        985 |
|       4 | 22-03-2013 |        985 |
+---------+------------+------------+
```

I need to show records from the table `task` and `account` such that only the oldest task can be shown and without showing the date. So the result will be:

```
+--------------+---------+
| account_name | task_id |
+--------------+---------+
| a            |       2 |
| b            |       7 |
| c            |       4 |
+--------------+---------+
```

Using `min` function came to my mind. But since I do not want to show the date, how can I use the function.

```
SELECT A.ACCOUNT_NAME, 
       T.TASK_ID, 
       MIN(T.TASK_DATE)  
  FROM ACCOUNT A  
 INNER JOIN TASK T  
    ON A.ACCOUNT_ID = T.ACCOUNT_ID  
 GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NAME, TASK_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use analytics:

```
SELECT account_name, task_id
  FROM (SELECT a.account_name,
               t.task_id,
               row_number() 
                  over(PARTITION BY a.account_id ORDER BY t.task_date) task_num
          FROM account a
         INNER JOIN task t ON a.account_id = t.account_id
         GROUP BY account_name, task_id)
 WHERE task_num = 1
```

or a self-join:

```
SELECT a.account_name, t.task_id
  FROM account a
 INNER JOIN task t ON a.account_id = t.account_id
 WHERE (t.account_id, t.task_date) = (SELECT t_in.account_id, 
                                             MIN(t_in.task_date) 
                                         FROM task t_in 
                                        GROUP BY t_in.account_id)
```

Comment: I tried the self-join and it works very find. beside its simplicity. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Another approach, a bit shorter:

```
select max(a.accountname) as account_name
     , max(t.taskid) keep(dense_rank first
                               order by t.taskdate) as task_id
 from account1 a
 join task t
   on (a.accountid = t.accountid)
group by a.accountid
```

result:

```
ACCOUNT_NAME    TASK_ID
------------ ----------
a                     2
b                     7
c                     4
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12b39/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a subquery:

```
SELECT S.ACCOUNT_NAME, S.TASK_ID FROM (
  SELECT A.ACCOUNT_NAME, T.TASK_ID, MIN(T.TASK_DATE)
  FROM ACCOUNT A
  INNER JOIN TASK T
  ON A.ACCOUNT_ID = T.ACCOUNT_ID
  GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NAME, TASK_ID
) S
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        A.ACCOUNT_NAME, 
        T.TASK_ID, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.TASK_ID 
                     ORDER BY T.TASK_DATE DESC) AS RowNbr
    FROM ACCOUNT A
    INNER JOIN TASK T
    ON A.ACCOUNT_ID = T.ACCOUNT_ID
)
SELECT
    CTE.ACCOUNT_NAME,
    CTE.TASK_ID
FROM
    CTE
WHERE 
    CTE.RowNbr=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple approach:

```
SELECT a.account_name, t.task_id
FROM   account a,
       task t
WHERE  a.account_id= t.account_id 
AND    t.task_date in (SELECT MIN(t.task_date))
GROUP BY account_name, task_id;
```

Comment: The `SELECT MIN(t.task_date)` is not a valid Oracle select statement. Unlike MS SQL Server, in Oracle you always have to select FROM somewhere, it means that the `FROM` clause is mandatory .

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov i wrote the query with mysql in my head.but if u want u can include 'from task' in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier than it may seem: after joining tables normally, just filter by the max(tak_date), that you can calculate on a simple sub-select.

```
SELECT acc.account_name, tsk.task_id
FROM account acc
JOIN task    tsk on (acc.account_id = tsk.account_id)
WHERE tsk.task_date = (
  SELECT MAX(aux.task_date)
  FROM task aux
  WHERE aux.account_id = tsk.account_id 
)
```